# Using a counter-controlled while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

The program should be print the numbers 0 through 10, along with their values doubled and tripled. The data file contains the necessary variable declarations and output statements.

Example the output:

```
single 1 double 2 triple 3
single 2 double 4 triple 6
single 3 double 6 triple 9
single 4 double 8 triple 12
```

here my code tell me if correct

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

        using namespace std;

        int main ()

        {


              int x, double, triple;
                int x = 0
                while (x<=10)

        {
            cout << "x" << double = (x*2) << triple = (x*3) << endl;
            x++;
        }
            return EXIT_SUCCESS
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What isn't working? Can you post specific bits of code you are having trouble with?

Comment: sorry i have no idea to do.. please help me :(

Comment: Here, you'll get help only if you can help yourself. No spoon feeding.

Comment: Reading some introductory programming tutorials would probably be a big help.

Comment: I'd try to break down the problem into smaller steps and then trying to code it. If you have no idea how to increment a counter, do simple multiplication and to print a statement, you may want to talk to your lecturer.

Comment: You have to show some code here before we jump in.

Comment: (Don’t [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/685766/using-a-counter-controlled-while-loop), especially to a *less*-fitting site.)

Comment: As Parcs has mentioned, at least show the code you have attempted to do, and maybe we can help you from there rather than just expecting us to do your homework. - oh and also, if you can at least tell us what language you are using to code, it will help as well so we can at least guide you to the correct library documentation that you can read up for self learning. (Synetech beats me to it)

Comment: Or at the very least tell us what language your class is using.

Comment: (Who [up-voted](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20462491/timeline)? ಠ_ఠ I’m Mr. Compassion, but even I can’t up-vote this as it is.)

Comment: We are not teachers. We can answer questions, if you have them, but we will not do it for you.

Comment: [`teach me please?`](http://superuser.com/questions/685766/using-a-counter-controlled-while-loop#comment870019_685766) @Jasis, we are not sure what you want. You have to clarify your problem, your goal, and at the very least, what language you are using. Is this a school assignment? Are you [trying to do something else](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/)?

Comment: yes this is school lab.. i will try to learn the c++ loop.. give me any idea  to do it?

Comment: That’s better; now we have something to work with. Here’s a few points: • You have a couple of syntax errors (missing `}` and `;`, `:` instead of `;`, unexpected `>>`, etc.) • You forgot to print `double` and `triple`. • Do you *have* to use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop?

Comment: how can I do to be perfect, this is my first program for loop.. i dont have any idea to do it..

Comment: see my code.. what is lack? and if corrrect my editing

Answer (score 1):

I'll attempt to put a guiding answer so I'm not going to give you a straight code that you can just copy and paste into your homework, but if you read and follow it, it should be the answer. (And next time, do go find your lecturer, or your tutor).

Some issues:

1. You are not printing the "Single" and "double" and "Triple" text which you should (based on your expected answer) So add that in.
2. You did your calculation to get the number for double, and triple - good. But again, you did not print them out.

Also C++ allows you to stack multiple cout all on one line, so for example:

```
cout << "My name is " << myname << endl;
```

Will print out:

```
My name is (content of variable myname)
```

And then print an end of line (endl). You can use that same technique to do part of your assignment to print out the results to meet the expected output.

Credit to Synetech

Comment: see my code.. what is lack? and if corrrect my editing

Answer (score 0):

you miss a lot of code in there. You didn't print nothing what you want 
try again with this inside while loop:

```
cout << “single “ << x << double << x*x
         <<“ triple “<< x*x*x << endl;

 x++;
```

Comment: Yeah it's look weir I know but noy my fault  the way it display